# Setting up IBM BPM sandbox for linux on Red Hat

Tags: linux, ibm-bpm

I'm trying to set up an IBM BPM sandbox on linux red hat for learning purposes. I'm currently following a guide I found on the web. In my current job, I'm using an in house BPM but I would like to expand my knowledge and learn a new BPM with more exposure.

The issue I have is that I need a eAssembly for IBM BPM on Linux. Is there a community/free version? Or are there any ways to learn to configure in IBM BPM, not for commercial reasons?

Bogdan

Answer (score 0):

There is no community edition IBM Business porcess Manager that you can download and install on Linux server.

You can review some of the Redbook which may help learn the concepts IBM-BPM

Business Process Management Deployment Guide ... - IBM Redbooks
https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg248175.pdf

IBM Business Process Manager Operations Guide - IBM Redbooks
www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg248356.pdf

---

There is a free trial version on the cloud you may want to check

"IBM Business Process Manager on Cloud"

https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/process-management-software-in-the-cloud